# Python Pandas DataFrame - data is displayed by indexes instead of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I'm just starting out in Python. I'm practicing web scraping Goodreads for book reviews. The scraping works and i'm 'appending' each page's data and then dumping all of it into a DataFrame. My problem is that I can not figure out how to get my data to display with columns, rows instead of columns, indexes. I would like all the book *titles under "Titles"* and *authors under "Authors"*, etc. Each index is a different webpage. This example includes three scraped urls. My DataFrame code is:

```
titlesFin = []
authorsFin = []
ratingsFin = []
reviewsFin = []

# find container with all books per page
    books = soup.find_all('tr', itemtype="http://schema.org/Book")

    titles = [removeWhite(title.find('a', class_='bookTitle').text).strip()
              for title in books]
    titlesFin.append(titles)
    authors = [author.find('a', class_='authorName').text for author in books]
    authorsFin.append(authors)
    reviews = soup.find_all('span', class_='minirating')
    reviewNums = [find_numbers(rate.text.strip()) for rate in reviews]
    ratings1, numRev = zip(*reviewNums)
    ratingsFin.append(ratings1)
    reviewsFin.append(numRev)

bookList = pd.DataFrame({
    'Title': titlesFin,
    'Author': authorsFin,
    'Rating': ratingsFin,
    'Reviews': reviewsFin, })

bookList.to_csv('GoodReadsxx.csv')
print(bookList)
```

**My current Dataframe output:**

```
                                               Title  \
0  [The Hunger Games (The Hunger Games, #1), Harr...   
1  [Moby-Dick or, the Whale, The Red Tent, The Se...   
2  [Thirteen Reasons Why, Wicked: The Life and Ti...   

                                              Author  \
0  [Suzanne Collins, J.K. Rowling, Harper Lee, Ja...   
1  [Herman Melville, Anita Diamant, Sue Monk Kidd...   
2  [Jay Asher, Gregory Maguire, James Clavell, Jo...   

                                              Rating  \
0  (4.33, 4.50, 4.28, 4.26, 3.59, 4.37, 3.94, 4.2...   
1  (3.50, 4.18, 4.05, 4.33, 4.56, 4.01, 4.26, 4.5...   
2  (3.93, 3.53, 4.39, 3.98, 4.06, 4.20, 4.35, 4.2...   

                                             Reviews  
0  (6,144,447, 2,387,048, 4,310,467, 2,855,826, 4...  
1  (466,455, 506,936, 1,089,483, 631,246, 2,462,7...  
2  (744,214, 563,831, 141,685, 371,866, 448,159, ...
```

***Data from a couple of the lists:***

```
titlesFin = [['The Hunger Games (The Hunger Games, #1)',
  'Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix (Harry Potter, #5)',
  'To Kill a Mockingbird',
  'Pride and Prejudice',
  'Twilight (Twilight, #1)',
  'The Book Thief',
  'Animal Farm',
  'The Chronicles of Narnia (Chronicles of Narnia, #1-7)',
  'J.R.R. Tolkien 4-Book Boxed Set: The Hobbit and The Lord of the Rings',
  'Gone with the Wind',

authorsFin:[['Suzanne Collins',
  'J.K. Rowling',
  'Harper Lee',
  'Jane Austen',
  'Stephenie Meyer',
  'Markus Zusak',
  'George Orwell',
  'C.S. Lewis',
  'J.R.R. Tolkien',
  'Margaret Mitchell',
  'John Green',
  'Douglas Adams',
  'Shel Silverstein',
  'Emily Brontë',
  'Dan Brown',
```

Comment: Thank you! I added (edited post) a little more code, I could add it all if necessary as it wouldn't be much more.

Comment: on a 2nd look ,your csv is fine, its just the display settings. when you open it in Excel or Notepad you'll see the columns are along the top. (the repeated indices should tip you off)

Comment: I still can't build your lists since the requests/URL you're scraping isn't included, but you have an extra `[]` around them instead of a 1d list based on your bottom snippet. What happens if you do `authorsFin.extend(authors)` (& same for the others)? This ensures your lists are flat. If it doesn't solve the problem, please show the request and URL to produce runnable code as a [mcve].

Comment: No, the csv has the same issue. cell a1='Title' and a2=all the titles in that one cell. same for the other headings.

Comment: Wow!! That was it! Extend instead of Append! Thank you!!!